# Confusion about the term "stochastic drift"

Tags: time-series, terminology, unit-root

After reading lots of material about the subject, I believe that **the term "stochastic drift" is defined in a two different ways.** These two different definitions make the term unambiguous and I assume that this is the reason you find so many questions regarding unit root testing and ADF.

**Definition one** (quoted of "Basic Econometrics" by Gujarati):

$Y_t = \beta_1 + Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$

which is a random walk with drift and therefore non stationary. If we write it as

$ \Delta Y_t = \beta_1 + \epsilon_t$

this means that $Y_t$ will exhibit a positive ($\beta_1 > 0$) or negative ($\beta_1 < 0$) trend. Such a trend is a stochastic trend.

**Definition two** (found in our professor his slides, wikipedia and this forum):

The random walk model with drift is given by

$Y_t = \beta_1 + Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$

Backward iterating the process yields:

$Y_t = \beta_1 + Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$

$=\beta_1 + \beta_1 + Y_{t-2} + \epsilon_t + \epsilon_{t-1}$

$=\beta_1 + \beta_1 + \beta_1 + Y_{t-3} + \epsilon_t + \epsilon_{t-1}  + \epsilon_{t-2}$

...

$=y_0 + \beta_1 t + \sum_{i=0}^{t-1} \epsilon_{t-i}$

The intercept in the non-stationary AR model adds a deterministic trend, i.e. $\beta_1  t$ to the stochastic trend $\sum_{i=0}^{t-1} \epsilon_{i-1}$.

**Wikipedia definition** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test)

Wikipedia derives exactly the same notation as in the slides of our professor, being:

$y_t=y_0 + \beta_1 t + \sum_{i=0}^{t-1} \epsilon_{t-i}$

But adds "with a deterministic trend coming from $\beta_1 t$ and a stochastic intercept term coming from $y_{0}+\sum_{i=0}^{t-1} \epsilon_{t-i}$, resulting in what is referred to as a stochastic trend."

**Conclusion and final question**

What terminology do you use? I think I like trend stationary and difference stationary the best. Furthermore, I also think the terms deterministic trend and stochastic trend are now clear to me. I don't like the way Gujarati and Wikipedia phrases it, I prefer definition two of the terms.

Comment: Could you please check the source of *Definition one*? Let's assume  for now that $\Delta Y_t = \beta_1$. This means that every time period $Y$ increases of $\beta_1$. $\beta_1$ is not a stochastic trend, but deterministic. In fact, after $t$ periods, you have a known increase of $\beta_1 t$, in line with definition two.

Comment: Could you also please check *definition two*? $\sum_{i=0}^{t-1} \epsilon_{t-1}$ does not look right: what happens to $i$ in the expression?

Comment: If you find an answer you deem correct it won't help you understand or be understood - as you've noticed, people don't seem to be very clear about it. Perhaps best to use a term that is clear: your model is *difference stationary*, unlike e.g. the *trend stationary* $Y_t = \beta_0 +\beta_1 t + \varepsilon_t$.

Comment: You were right, there is was a typo in definition two. I will also update the question with the definition of wikipedia.

Comment: There are various types of [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk), and they do tend to drift from the origin with time. However, there is more to non-stationarity than random walk. For example, all heart rates eventually stop, and stationarity terminates. In general, when the constant parameters of an assumed model actually change, the assumption of stationarity is violated.